# How to use enum value to set header for a tab item of a tab-control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums, tabcontrol

I want to get the header of a selected tab-item of a tab-control and activate another tab-item of another tab-control appropriately, eg. select tab "A"/"B" of tab-control TC1 will activate tab "A"/"B" on tab-control TC2.

I want "A", "B", ... to be a enum value so that no string comparation is used. So, how can I use an enum value to set the tab-item's header?

[Edit] And yes, I prefer to use the enum value directly in XAML codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say use a WPF [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

In Xaml,
`<Tab Header={Binding PropThatReturnsTheEnum, Converter=EnumToDisplayTextConverter}>....</Tab>`

On the other hand, if you're implying that you want to set the text of the tab to a named member of an enumeration hardcoded in XAML, you could use the Static MarkupExtension

`<Tab Header={x:Static local:MyEnum.Member1}>... </Tab>`